# Airflow task stuck indefinitely in queu state

Tags: airflow

I configured airflow on Openshift platform and connect it to LDAP.

I had a lot of trouble running my DAGS. What happend: Many time the DAG started and the task are stuck in queu mode infinitely.

I just saw a log in the airflow web-server pod INFO: updated user Airflow Admin INFO: Login failed for user: airflow

This log is reccurent (every few seconds it's been print). I also try to login via UI with airflow user it's not working. I understand that since airflow is bind to LDAP and in my LDAP server there is no airflow user this log occur.

I had an airflow user to ldap but still the task are stuck in queu mode.

Someone maybe know why?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution and it was not about the LDAP.

For a very little instant (less than a second) the airflow-worker pod was crashing due to OOM.
It was hard to spot it.

After giving more ressource to the airflow-worker everything looks great.

What i think is: tasks have been started , but du to memory limitation the airflow-worker crashed and when restarting forgot about the runs that started before, then didn't take them to the running state(or other state).

The ressource that i gave to the worker was about 2gig of memory i upgrade it to 4 and it work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution!
I just want to add for future users coming by that another very common solution is to enable [stalled_task_timeout](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#stalled-task-timeout).

Comment: Hello @David Belhamou, Thanks for sharing the response. I'm struggling to deploy Airflow in Openshift, could you share with me a deployment template please? I m looking for a minimalistic configuration (dev environment)

Comment: I sadly can't share with you the config i use at work (some internal reason) but i can direct you to a tool that will help you. got https://kompose.io/getting-started/. this tool convert any docker-compose into yamls and you can add an option for openshit. kompose convert --provider=openshift <you-docker-compose>. And after that you just need to make oc apply to your new yamls file.